# Detect conditions of an if statements using Bison and Flex in C++

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, parser-generator

I want to get all the conditions of an if statement in C++. If I put `(foo&&bar&&(one&&two))`, then I want to print `foo - bar - one - two`.

I've compiled the scanner.l and parser.y files, and tested individually: `my yy.lex.c` works: if I put `(a&&b)`, then I get 5 tokens: `(`, `a`, `&&`, `b` and `)` as I want. But when I'm using the .y file, if I put the same input, then I get `a&&b` and `b)`. Note that in this case I get 2 tokens, because the token `a&&b` should be separated into 3 tokens `a`, `&&` and `b` . I've tried introducing a simpler condition: `(a)` then I get: `(` and `a)` but I want to get `(`, `a`, `)`.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or is a bug; I hope it is my fault.

**parser.y**

```
%{
    #include <iostream>
    #include <list>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int yylex(void);
    void yyerror(char *);

    list<string> tokenList;

    #define YYSTYPE char *
%}

%token  PAR_IZQ
        PAR_DER
        SIMBOLO
        FIN
        NADA
        AND
        OR

%start input

%%

input:

    |   input terminos
;

terminos:
        PAR_IZQ terminos PAR_DER    { }
    |   PAR_IZQ condicion PAR_DER   { }
;

condicion:
        terminos AND terminos       { }
    |   SIMBOLO AND terminos        { cout << " 1) CONDITION FOUND: " << $1 << endl; }
    |   terminos AND SIMBOLO        { cout << " 2) CONDITION FOUND: " << $3 << endl; }
    |   SIMBOLO AND SIMBOLO         { cout << " 3) CONDITION FOUND: " << $3 << " AND " << $1 << endl; }
    |   SIMBOLO                     { cout << " 4) CONDITION FOUND: " << $1 << endl; }
;

%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(void) {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

**scanner.l**

```
%option noyywrap
%{
    #include <iostream>
    #include "parser.tab.c"
    using namespace std;
%}

%%

[a-zA-Z0-9]+  {
    yylval = yytext;
    return SIMBOLO;
}

"&&" {
    return AND;
}

"||" {
    return OR;
}

[ \0\0] {
    return FIN;
}

"("     {
    yylval = yytext;
    return PAR_IZQ;
}

")"     {
    yylval = yytext;
    return PAR_DER;
}

.       {
    cout << "Entrada no permitida.";
    cout << endl << yytext << endl;
    exit(1);
}

%%
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "lex.yy.c"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef yy_buffer_state *YY_BUFFER_STATE;
extern int yyparse();
extern YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_buffer(char *, size_t);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char condition[] = "(a) \0\0";
    // note yy_scan_buffer is looking for a double null string
    yy_scan_buffer(condition, sizeof(condition));
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that the input of the parser is a string, so I have to pass it as a paramenter of the `yy_scan_buffer` function. The `\0\0` is necessary because otherwise the program would never end its execution. The console says in red "syntax error", but I don't know why!

[image]

Do yo know how can I fix it and get the tokens that I want?

Thanks!

**PS**: I'm using *Windows 8.1, Qt creator 2.8.1, win_bison 2.7 and win_flex 2.5.37*.

Comment: Offtopic but still: I can really recommend using Flexc++ and Bisonc++ (not to be confused with bison++ and flex++). Those will generate proper C++ code for you to work with, instead of that `yy_` stuff ;-)

Comment: I suspect you need to increase the look-ahead of the parser.

Comment: If you want to do this seriously, you will need a C++ grammar that matches what is in use, and all the C++ front end machinery (macro expansion, name resolution, template instantiation, ... all the way up to handling features of C++14 since it is virtually a standard as of this moment).  Rolling a very simple grammar will not help.   If you doing this for an educational experience, then boogie on and ignore me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your lexer returns `yytext` to the parser as the `yylval` associatated with symbol tokens, but `yytext` is a pointer into the lexer's internal token buffer, which will only be valid until the next token is read.  So when you later go to print out the tokens in your condition, you get semi-random garbage (since it is soon after, you mostly just get the same raw token buffer with no terminating null characters).

You need to make a copy of the string pointed at by `yytext` before returning it to the parser:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+  {
    yylval = strdup(yytext);
    return SIMBOLO;
}
```

of course, you also need to keep track of when the string is no longer needed and `free` it.

Alternately, since you're not using `%union`, change your `#define` for `YYSTYPE` to

```
#define YYSTYPE  std::string
```